# Configuring React with Asp.net MVC4,getting error like Failed to load resource[app.jsx] in browser

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, reactjs.net

***Index.cshtml***

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

<div id="content"></div>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/react/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/app.jsx")"></script>
```

***app.jsx***

```
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>Hello World!!</div>
        );
}
});
```

getting error in browser like

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Comment: start your app in debug mode and see what exception it gives you

Answer (score 4):

Resolved this issue with following steps,

1) Make a sure installed React.Web.Mvc4 Package, it is named in NuGet manager as 
    `ReactJS.NET`

2) Install the following packages from NuGet manager,

```
 JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8
 JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x64
 JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.Native.win-x86
```

3) In `App_Start` directory update a file `ReactConfig.cs`

```
    public static void Configure()
    {
        JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
        JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
    }
```

4) Clean, Build the solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code seems to be ok.

You can look at the url that give you error 500 on the browser.
localhost/.../.jsx

you may have something like this

[image: Error]

If you looks at https://reactjs.net/getting-started/aspnet.html

[image: Install those NuGet]

On your project you must have reactconfig.cs

[image: reactconfig.cs file]

you need to configurare as in the picture

[image: reactconfig]

that's it.

Comment: I only configured as follows: 
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
I did not add the .AddScript("~/Scripts/bla/bla") and the MVC Razor view finds and renders the jsx file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to transpile your `.jsx` files to `.js` with babel or web compiler (install from VS extensions) and reference those from the view. Also, remove the second `react` lib:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/react/react.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding this to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => 
     {
           options.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
           options.EngineFactories.AddV8();
     }
);
```